# how to generate results in matrix either using sql or hive or python or PySpark

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables with which Between demo and demo extract, how does the value of age_range change for KBM households?

I'm looking for a matrix where the sum of all cells of KBM household IDs.  The rows are the value of age_range from demo and the columns are the value of k_age_range for xtract.

I tried to group my data using this.

Select  age_range, k_age_range, household_id from demo As demo, extract As extract where demo.id = extract.id Group By demo.age_range, demo.kbm_household_id, extract.k_age_range

There are two tables

demo

id     age_range       kbm_household_id

1         A          AGYDGYDGYEW

2         B          AGYDGYDFDGD

3         C           AGYDGYDGUGH

extract

id     k_age_range    kbm_household_id

1          1            AGYEWUCUXUI

2          2            AGERWREUUSS

3          3            AGYDWTSHAJG

Result I am getting is this

age_range        k_age_range         kbm_household_id

Blank              1                231

Blank              2                432

Blank              3                864

I want an output like a matrix to be like

```
       k_age_range
```

age_range        1            2         3

```
 A          231          472       864

 B          931          532       864

 C          321          332       864
```

Comment: Please explain how you get your numbers

Comment: @nbk what I am trying is to get the grouped values from demo.age_range as header of rows and extract.k_age_range as 1st column of matrix. Once this is done I want values for kbm_household_id already present in table demo.

Comment: @nbk if you need I can provide more insight on this.

Comment: try this it is  it combines all columns only in rows , so that you need php, python or javascript to show it as you wanted Select d.age_range ,d.kbm_household_id,e.k_age_range,e.kbm_household_id 
From demo d cross join extract e
order by age_range,k_age_range;

Comment: @nbk this doesn't work

Comment: what doesn't look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/753377/13